# How to get the status code from within the HTTP request handler

Tags: go

In my request handler I have a conditional statement where I need to fetch the http status code.

```
func PostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    idStr := params["id"]

    // how would I get the 307 status code, to decide whether to redirect or not?
    if w.StatusCode != 307 { // does not work, no such field - why not???
        http.Redirect(w, r, idStr, 307)
    } else {
        RenderTemplate()
    }
}

m.HandleFunc("/{id:.*}", PostHandler).Methods("POST") // this is matched first to intercept POST requests with status 307
m.HandleFunc("/{id:.*}", MyHandler).Methods("GET", "POST")
```

I've made an example to help illustrate this concrete scenario:

http://play.golang.org/p/YZgTsVO524

How would I achieve this?

Basically I'm using the 307 because I need to resend my POST values the http.Redirect(w,r, url, code) destination. Afaik this seems to be the best way to do this, but again, I can't do it without the status code.

Additional question: is using 307 a bad solution? If so, what's a better alternative?

Comment: Heh the example above was just made quick to illustrate the overall problem. But yes, you're of course right, a typo. ;-)

Comment: The response writer does not have a readable status field because it's what **you're returning**. The request has a StatusCode member if this is what you mean.

Comment: What status code are you talking about? Status code is server (your handler) response

Comment: I'm getting: "r.StatusCode undefined (type *httpRequest has no field or method StatusCode" - any idea what to do then?

Comment: The [`http.Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response) type has a `StatusCode` field but that is not available from a handler, it's the handler's job to write the response (via `http.ResponseWriter`) and the standard `net/http` package doesn't make the current partially written response available to handlers. If you're chaining handlers together it's your job to keep/pass any required state (like the response code an earlier handler picked) between them.

Comment: could something like `ResponseRecorder` used in https://justinas.org/writing-http-middleware-in-go/ work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand what you're trying to do, your question is very misleading though. As mentioned by many people, you don't have access to *previously* issued response code on request performed as a consequence of redirection (not because Go doesn't provide it but HTTP doesn't handle your scenario the way you want it). The original and redirected requests are two separate HTTP requests occurring in two different times in your application. It means you can't easily distinguish between brand new and redirected requests if they're *exactly* the same.

The following solutions pop into my mind:

1. When sending 307 response code, you're supposed to provide a new URI in the `Location` header. You can choose different URL path, so it can be routed to a separate handler (handling only redirected requests). Other option would be to use the same path, but add a parameter, for example attaching `&redirected=1` to the URL – by parsing parameters you can then detect new vs redirected requests.
2. Use GET instead of POST for redirected requests if possible. If POST data is essential for the second request you would need to take it somehow from the database or wherever you stored the original POST content. Using code 302 instead of 307 would – to my understanding – require clients to always follow redirection using GET method. You can then use `Request.Method` to distinguish between new vs redirected requests.
3. Keep state within your application and track what was already POSTed. This would require some unique identifier per request – if you have it and store it you could then check whether request is completely new or was performed before (assuming redirection).

Comment: I can rule option 2 and 3 out, but I kinda like your idea 1a. In the end I decided to make a custom route endpoint /{something:.*}/{else:.*}/{id:.*} which I'm inserting in the form action followed by an optional ?redirectTo=id. Thanks man.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is this:

> how would I get the 307 status code, to decide whether to redirect or not

You are trying to decide if you need to redirect or not in a HTTP *Request Handler*. In a request handler you do not *receive* the status code, you *send* the status code as part of the response.

Comment: I don't understand why is answer was upvoted so much already. I need this functionality in my application (pretty essential), I believe it ought to be possible somehow, and this is not really helping me finding a solution to the specific problem. Maybe my example wasn't clear enough - I'll revise it ASAP, and explain exactly what it's supposed to do shortly.

Comment: @Dac0d3r: this was upvoted because an http client *does not* send a status code. Until your handler has generated a code, either explicitly, or implicitly when returning, a status code *does not exist*.  If you want to set a 307, then you can call WriteHeader yourself, or use the http.Redirect helper function.

Comment: Let me explain what's happening (or the intended behavior). 1) POST request is fired, 2) request is intercepted by the first handler. 3) the post handler checks if the ResponseWriter has the status code 307 or not 4) If it doesn't (I'll assume  this request was fired from the form submit), I'll redirect to the new destination using 307 POST request. 5) the handler will once again intercept this new redirected 307 POST request, but now, since the status code is 307, it'll not redirect, but just render the template.Did you by any chance miss 307 POST being intercepted again by the post handler?

Comment: @Dac0d3r when the second request is being issued, there is no 307 status code associated with it. What makes you think handler keeps track of the redirections and then matches them with the new (redirected) requests? You should be able to recognise redirected requests by URL (assuming you're not redirecting to exactly the same URL as original request).

Comment: @tomasz idea of using the url is actually a pretty good alternative. It would probably work in this specific case. However the best workaround-solution SO FAR is probably the one Jackie Li proposes here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/_44ehpmFOjU - what Martin Angers calls: "augmented" response writer to intercept the calls to get the status code. I tried implementing it here http://play.golang.org/p/uxvRfVJffO but I can't get it to work yet.